# SQL query to find the bus travelling through route

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin, xampp

Having a table name route, contains the bus_id,stop_name and position(it is the sequence of the stops).

> bus travel in one way according to position

**Table: route**

```
| bus_id | stop_name | position |
|--------|-----------|----------|
| 1      | Stop_1    | 1        |
| 1      | Stop_2    | 2        |
| 1      | Stop_3    | 3        |
| 1      | Stop_4    | 4        |
| 1      | Stop_5    | 5        |
| 1      | Stop_6    | 6        |
| 1      | Stop_7    | 7        |
| 2      | Ramdom_1  | 1        |
| 2      | Ramdom_2  | 2        |
| 2      | Stop_3    | 3        |
| 2      | Stop_4    | 4        |
| 2      | Stop_5    | 5        |
| 2      | Stop_6    | 6        |
| 2      | Ramdom_3  | 7        |
```

Now need to find the bus_id which go from stop_3 to stop_6 i.e bus_id = `1` and `2`

examples:\

1. from `stop_1` to `stop_6` = `1`\
2. from `stop_6` to `Ramdom_3` = `2`\
3. from `stop_6` to `stop_1` = `no bus found`\

Need to MYSQL query to find the above data

> database used Server version: 10.4.21-MariaDB (xamp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select a.*, b.* 
From route a
Join route b on a. bus_id=b.bus_id
Where a.position <b.position
And a.name=[stopname] and b.name=. 
[stopname]
```